# Custom column names in HDF5 file using h5py

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, hdf5, h5py

I have the following code snippet:

```
import h5py
import numpy

## Data set with shape (5, 5) and numpy array containing column names as string
data = numpy.random.random((5, 5))
column_names = numpy.array(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])

## Create file pointer
fp = h5py.File("data_set.HDF5", "w")

## Store data
fp["sub"] = data

## Close file
fp.close()
```

How do I add the names for the columns in the `HDF5 file` as indicated by the arrow in the included figure?

[image]

Comment: Did you try using attributes `attrs` ?

Comment: I think this [link](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/HL/H5TB_Spec.html) might help.

Comment: @AnuragReddy What would be the right syntax? I have tried: `fp.attrs["FIELD_MANY"] = column_names`, `fp.attrs["column_name"] = column_names`, `fp.attrs["column_1_name"] = "a"`. However, this does not produce the desired result.

Comment: `h5py` uses numpy arrays, not `tables`.  These arrays don't use custom row or column labels.  `numpy` structured arrays use field names, but I'm not sure you want to change your arrays just to get names.  `pandas` uses pytables to interface with HDF5.  You could try loading your array into a dataframe and saving that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use a Numpy dtype to define the field/column names, then use it to define a record array. You can also mix variable types (say if you want to mix ints, floats and strings on the same line).

Modified example below:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

## Data set with shape (5, 5) and list containing column names as string
data = np.random.rand(5, 5)
col_names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
## Create file pointer
with h5py.File("data_set_2.HDF5", "w") as fp :
    ds_dt = np.dtype( { 'names':col_names,
                        'formats':[ (float), (float), (float), (float), (float)] } )
    rec_arr = np.rec.array(data,dtype=ds_dt)        
    ## Store data
    ##fp["sub"] = data
    ds1 = fp.create_dataset('sub', data=rec_arr )
```